# Windows 10 customize task bar visiblity

Tags: windows, display, taskbar

I want to completely disable my taskbar on my 1st monitor.

I found a way where I have to set the 2nd monitor as main and "Show on all displays" to false.

I still want to have my 1st monitor as my main monitor, otherwise all programs are opening on the 2nd monitor. Any ideas?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I download a tool named taskbar hide in my computer which has two monitors. I combined the tool with your method(turn show on all displays off) then achieved your needs. Here is the link to download may help you:[Taskbar Hide](https://filehippo.com/download_taskbar_hide/).[how to set the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2i2R.jpg).

Comment: Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!